# How do I filter elements in an array that both match a pattern and don't match a second pattern?

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I have the following expression for only keeping elements in an array that match a certain pattern:

```
lines.grep(/^[[:space:]]*\d+/)
```

How do I write a Ruby expression that keeps elements in an array that both match a pattern and don't match a second pattern?  That is, I want to keep elements that match the above, but then also exclude elements that match:

```
/^[[:space:]]*\d+[:.]/
```

If my array contains only the element `" 123 23:25 "`, the result should contain this original element because it starts with a number that doesn't contain a ":" or "." after it.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We'd like a better example of what you're trying to, including the minimal code demonstrating what you tried, the smallest input data and expected output. We don't know your expertise level, so we'd have to write a tutorial rather than tweak your code. Also, please take the time to make sure your spelling and grammar are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
/^[[:space:]]*\d++(?![:.])/
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Giu4EW/2).

Here, `^[[:space:]]*` part is the same as in the first regex, `\d++` will possessively match 1+ digits (thus, deactivating backtracking) and `(?![:.])` will fail any match if those 1+ digits are followed with either `:` or `.`.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line
- `[[:space:]]*`  - (may be replaced with `\s*`) - 0+ whitespace characters
- `\d++` - 1+ digits matches possessively so that backtracking into the pattern was not possible
- `(?![:.])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if `:` or `.` is found immediately to the right of the current location (after 1+ digits).

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work.  If my array contains only the element " 123 23:25 ", running linese.grep(/^(?!.*\d[:.])[[:space:]]*\d+/) results in an empty array. By what I want, it should at least contain the original element because the original element starts with a number that doesn't contain a ":" or ".".

Comment: Hi Cary, I wanted to give your suggestion a try, but running lines.grep(/^[[:space:]]*\d+(?![:.])/) when lines is [" 12:25  1234"] returns [" 12:25  1234"] even though I don't want it to.

Comment: Please see my edit. You need `\d++`, a `++` possessive quantifier with `\d`.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I tried your new expression, lines.grep(/^(?!.*\d[:.])[[:space:]]*\d+/) , but if lines is [" 1234 12:25 "] , nothing is returned, even though the element should be returned back since it starts with a number and not a number with a ":" in it.

Comment: My *new* suggestion is `/^[[:space:]]*\d++(?![:.])/`. See the **EDIT** part at the bottom. Please revise your question, and make sure you post actual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the general case of your question.

Try this

```
lines.select { |each| each =~ first_pattern && each !~ second_pattern }
```

Or if you use Ruby 2.3+

```
lines.grep(first_pattern).grep_v(second_pattern)
```

The name of `grep_v` is inspired by the `grep -v` command line options.